# What are the strange planks for?

Tags: hammerwatch

Occasionally I find fairly well hidden "Strange Planks". What are these used for? I haven't found anywhere they're tracked, or anything to do with them. I thought maybe I could repair broken bridges, but I don't know how.

Comment: Add a picture perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

This answer contains major spoilers for the end of the game. Here be dragons. Proceed at your own risk.

> After defeating the final boss of the game, the dungeon begins to collapse. You must use the planks to provide yourself a path to the exit. If you do not have enough planks, the dungeon collapses around you, and it's game over.

Answer (score 1):

They are rudimentary in making your escape from the castle after you slay the final boss. If you do not collect them all you will not be able to complete the game and will di. It is still considered a victory because the boss is slain, yet the Heroes are lost.

Answer (score 0):

They're required to get the full ending. Collect them all.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this answer spoils the game ending.

> Strange Planks are used to escape the collapsing castle after defeating the last boss. If playing on Steam, escaping via this route grants you an achievement. You will need every single one available in order to actually escape.